# Pseudo Class :current

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am trying to make my menu bar `background` go black when you are on that page, eg. if you're on the SFX page the SFX tab will be black, not red.

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="menuBar" align="left">
    <table cellspacing="5" >
        <tr>
            <td><a href="index2.php">Home</a></td>
            <td><a href="editorial.php">Editorial</a></td>
            <td><a href="sfx.php">SFX</a></td>
            <td><a href="occasion.php">Occasion</a></td>
            <td><a href="artwork.php">Artwork</a></td>
            <td><a href="body.php">Body Painting</a></td>
            <td><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></td>
            <td><a href="about.php">About</a></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And My CSS:

```
#menuBar {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 810px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 53px;
    vertical-align:central;
}
#menuBar a {
    background: #AA0000;
    padding-top: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    padding-left: 11px;
    padding-right: 11px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    color: Beige;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
    font-family: Gabriola,"Lucida Grande", "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Sans", "DejaVu Sans", Verdana, sans-serif;    
}

#menuBar a:hover {
    background: #000000;
    transition:all .3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all .3 ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#menuBar a:focus {
    background:#000000;
}

#menuBar a:current {
    background:#000000;
}
```

I've tried everything, and its not working. I'm sure it's something simple, but i don't know what it is

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Besides being a brand new pseudo-class that was introduced only relatively recently, [`:current` does not mean what you think it means](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#the-current-pseudo). Ironically, the same draft does propose another new pseudo-class for links to the current document, called [`:local-link`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#local-pseudo), but neither of these are implemented because they've only just recently been proposed. (In fact, I just discovered that `:local-link` has been removed from the [Selectors 4 ED](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4) as of May 2014 — no idea why, but odds that such a pseudo-class ever gets implemented just got much worse.)

Either way, there is currently no pseudo-class for links that point to the current page. You will need to use PHP to determine which of these links points to the current page, add a `class="current"` to the appropriate element, and target that class.